# Kafka Streams with suppress() reprocessing changelog

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka Streams version 2.1) application with a Kafka Streams binder and I am doing time window aggregations, where I only want to make some action (API call) once
        the window closes. The behavior I'm observing is that on every application restart, my mapValues function is called for every record stored in the changelog, 
        resulting in huge number of calls being made to the API.

My understanding of suppress() is that for every closed time window, a tombstone record should be sent to the aggregate changelog topic, effectively preventing me from reprocessing it, even after application restarts.

What could be causing messages to be reprocessed on an app restart?

I've already confirmed that the app is not reconsuming the source topic.

Snippet of the relevant code below:

```
    Serde<Aggregator> aggregatorSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Aggregator.class, objectMapper);

    Materialized<String, TriggerAggregator, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> stateStore = Materialized.<String, Aggregator, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
        with(Serdes.String(), aggregatorSerde);

    KTable<Windowed<String>, List<Event>> windowedEventKTable = inputKStream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .aggregate(Aggregator::new, ((key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.aggregate(value)), stateStore)
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()).withName(supressStoreName))
        .mapValues((windowedKey, groupedTriggerAggregator) -> {//code here returning a list})
        .toStream((k,v) -> k.key())
        .flatMapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value);
```

Comment: Might be a bug? Can you try out 2.3.1 release?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy for me to do since I'm pulling Kafka Streams through spring cloud stream kafka streams binder. (In hindsight, a terrible choice)

Asking this question gave me a hunch to check whats going on on the internal topic, and I'm actually not seeing tombstone records being sent, even though I've caused few time windows to be closed.

Should tombstone records be sent right after the time window closes, to the state store topic?

Comment: No. For windowed aggregations, data is the changelog topic is aged out -- it's configured with policy `"compact,delete"`. There are not tombstones written.